# В Discord и в доте как работает групповой звонок? Через VoIP?

Tags: webrtc, voip, discord-api

Интересует вопрос, с помощью какой технологии (webRTc. VoIP и др) в доте, дискорде работает групповой звонок? Передача голоса в интернете
Спасибо за ответ и подсказки!

Answer (score 0):

## Discotd

https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/43z4yh/open_source_protocol_encryption_privacy/cznvmxl

DiscordDan [Customer Experience]

> We're allergic to data selling and ads. You won't find a trace of that around us here.
>   As for encryption, it depends on what you're using and what platform (mobile or PC)
>   `TLS` for text chat, etc
>   `DTLS` for voice over browser
>   `xsalsa20` for voice over desktop app
>   We don't have plans to go Open Source.

---

https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/5m5tdu/what_protocol_does_discord_use_a_form_of_webrtc/

ReallyAmused [Computer Man]

> It's just `RTP` over `UDP` encrypted with `DTLS` or `xalsa20`.
>   More info here: https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/voice-connections

LionUCS

> `RTP` can be done in `JS`?

ReallyAmused [Computer Man]

> yeah via `WebRTC`...